# How do I change the running app icon for Yahoo! Messenger?

Tags: macos, yahoo-messenger

I'm using Yahoo Messenger for work however the giant smiley face looks very unprofessional on my dock. I changed the App icon the normal way and it works when the program isn't running, however when the program is running it swaps out the icon with its default one.

How do I change the app icon for yahoo messenger for when the program is running?

I don't see the specific running icon in the app package.